# C++ Array address allocation to pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am quite new to the concept of pointers and recently came across this line of code:

```
int arr[]={1,2,3};
int (*p)[3] = &arr;
```

What is the difference between the above lines of code and this:

```
int arr[]={1,2,3};
int *p = arr;
```

And why does this give error:

```
int arr[]={1,2,3};
int *p = &arr;
```

Comment: I guess you should learn programming elsewhere, because here people wont like it. e.g. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/

Comment: This one is not too bad a question, other than the third part which is standard array decay and well explained here: [What is array decaying?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Comment: It's a "type" thing. Once you can accurately describe what the *type* of `p` is in each case, and the *type* of the expression you're assigning to it, the clarity will be self-revealing, both for why the first two examples compile without complaint, and why the third does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Difference in types**

The type of `p` in

```
int (*p)[3] = &arr;
```

is `int (*)[3]`, i.e. a pointer to an array of `3` `int`s.

The type of `p` in:

```
int *p = arr;
```

is simply `int*`, i.e. a pointer to an `int`.

**As a consequence,**

In the first case,

`*p` evaluates to an array of 3 `int`s, i.e. `int [3]`.

In the second case,

`*p` evaluates to just an `int`.

---

To get the first element of `arr`, you'll have to use `(*p)[0]` or `p[0][0]` in the first case.

To get the first element of `arr`, you'll have to use `*p` or `p[0]` in the second case.

---

To get the last element of `arr`, you'll have to use `(*p)[2]` or `p[0][2]` in the first case.

To get the last element of `arr`, you'll have to use `*(p+2)` or `p[2]` in the second case.

Answer (score 2):

They're just different things.

```
int arr[]={1,2,3};
int (*p1)[3] = &arr; // pointer to array (of 3 ints)
int *p2 = arr;       // pointer to int
```

`p1` is a pointer to array (of 3 ints), then initialized to pointing to `arr`. `p2` is a pointer to int, as the result of [array-to-pointer decay](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array-to-pointer_decay), it's initialized to pointing to the 1st element of `arr`.

Then you can use them as:

```
(*p1)[0]; // same as arr[0]
p1[0][1]; // same as arr[1], note p1[1] will be ill-formed.
p2[0];    // same as arr[0]
```